# Difference between laravel value() function and direct model access

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm doing an Eloquent query in my Profession model, i ran an where query, retrieve the first value, then caught only the value in "id" column with ->value('id')

```php
//This always return 1
$profession = Profession::where('name', $profession)->first()->value('id');
//This return the right value
$profession = Profession::where('name', $profession)->first()->id;
```

Does value() function depends on some other aspect of the query/configuration? Couldn't find anything in Laravel query builder documentation.

Comment: Which Laravel Version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Profession::where('name', $profession)->first()` returns a model. You cannot call `value` on a model. However, you may call it on a query builder as explained in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results)?

So instead of calling

```
$profession_id = Profession::where('name', $profession)->first()->id;
```

you could achive the same thing with

```
$profession_id = Profession::where('name', $profession)->value('id');
```

Comment: It make sense that an query command would work properly when in a query, hahaha. Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a helper function in laravel with the name value . It will always returns that value it is given for example value(true) is true 
But for eloquent if you want to access the fields either you use pluck function like ->pluck(id) it will give you ids only